# Spring JPA - Link 2 tables with no parent-child relationship

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to link 2 entities with no parent-child relationship using @Many to one relationship?

Given below, Product and Shop have the same primary key productID. One product can be sold at many shops, but there is no parent child relationship.

**How will I map Product to Shop so that when a Product is retrieved, the list of shops it is sold at is also retrieved?**

```
@Entity
public class Product {
@Id
private String productID;
private String productName;
private String productStatus;
private Timestamp creationTs;
private List<String> productFeedback;
}

@Entity
public class Shop {
@Id
private String productID;
private String location;
private double salesPerDay;
private TimeStamp latestTs;
}
```

Comment: As any JPA document would tell you, you put a relation annotation (`@OneToMany`, `@ManyToOne`, `@OneToOne`, and `@ManyToMany`) when you have a relation. If you dont have a relation then you dont put one. This is object-oriented programming ...

Comment: why not just create a thrid entity that links between `Product` and `Shop` ?